# mysql: select distinct column in table?

Tags: mysql

im trying to select distinct, the column 'content' in my table reviews,

it works when i do this:

```
function get_new_reviews() {
            global $connection;
            global $_SESSION;
            $query = "SELECT DISTINCT r.content
                        FROM ptb_reviews r, ptb_profiles p
                        WHERE r.to_user_id =".$_SESSION['user_id']."
                        AND r.deleted = '0'
                        AND r.read_review = '0'
                        AND r.approved = '0'
                        AND r.from_user_id != '0'
                        ORDER BY r.date_added DESC 
                        LIMIT 0, 14";


                        $reviews_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
            confirm_query($reviews_set);
            return $reviews_set;
        }
```

but i also need columns

```
r.from_user_id, p.display_name, r.id reviews_id, r.date_added
```

and when i try and add them in it has lots of the same content going down the page, is there a way i can just select all fields in my table but only distinct select the content column?

thanks

Comment: At least one of those columns must be changing; as such, which of the multiple possible values do you want to select?

Comment: i want to select all columns but set column 'content' to select distinct

Comment: Have you tried `GROUP BY` that specific column?

Comment: Yes, I understand that... but for a given "distinct" value of `content`, say `'thisvalue'`, there must be more than one set of values for the other columns (otherwise you wouldn't observe the behaviour you describe).  Therefore, which of those multiple possible values do you wish to select for each distinct value of `content`?

Comment: @RolandoIsidoro: That will result in indeterminate values in the other (aka "hidden") columns, hence why I ask the OP to specify which particular values he seeks.

Comment: Perhaps some example data would help?

Answer (score 0):

I think that is what you are looking for mate:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT r.content, r.from_user_id, p.display_name, r.id reviews_id, r.date_added
    FROM ptb_reviews r, ptb_profiles p
    WHERE r.to_user_id =".$_SESSION['user_id']."
        AND r.deleted = '0'
        AND r.read_review = '0'
        AND r.approved = '0'
        AND r.from_user_id != '0'
    GROUP BY r.content
    LIMIT 0, 14
) t1
ORDER BY date_added DESC
```

Comment: That query gives unpredictable result and certainly shouldn't be used. Selecting non-aggregated columns that aren't in the group by statement is wrong 99,9% of time.

Comment: That doesn't change anything. You still can't predict what r.from_user_id will be returned for given r.content if there is more than one candidate.